# Load a video from an external resource in my web hosting

Tags: html, video, streaming, hosting

I have a simple web page written in HTML for testing video streaming.

```
<video controls name="media">
    <source src="external_url.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

That's work in local, but when I upload the page on my free web hosting, the page doesn't load any video. Is there a workaround? Maybe using an embedded player?

**update**

I've discovered that's a problem related to video. Unfortunately I cannot link it because it's for a private presentation, but I've tried with other videos and that works well. Any idea why my video doesn't play?

Comment: Have you checked the format of your URL to make sure it isn't pointing to a local file?

Comment: Yes, it's pointing to an external video.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please check that the URL is intact.
2. Check if there might be some file discrepancies. The control currently supports mp4, ogg, and webm as seen [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp).
3. Use the `canPlayType()` method to test the site AFTER the upload - just to be sure we're covered on that front. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) for the DOM reference.
4. You can fiddle around [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video_controls) if you don't want to have to upload the site first before live-testing it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried with other videos as you suggested and I've discovered that those work. I've update my question, please read that.

Comment: @f_ficarola perhaps you can update the question/post a comment with the video's link..? 
Also, I suspect that the video's host might have some restriction as pertains who sent the request for the video.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot. It's a video for a project to propose as research, it's not mine. Maybe, the partner's server has some restriction, I don't know. I even tried to host my HTML page in my local Apache web server and load it from a virtual machine... It doesn't work, so it's not a problem from my free web hosting, but from the server hosting the video.

Comment: Aah, if it has failed from even the VM, the issue might be stemming from the host. Did you try to load it from a browser in the VM?

Comment: Actually, if I try to directly open the video file from a browser (real or virtual machines) Chrome plays it. Vice versa, if I link the video into a HTML page and I host the page in web server (remote or local), and then I tried to open that page, the video doesn't start. So I think that the server hosting this video has some restriction on requests.

Comment: It must be an issue with the hosting server, and the video request's identities. I guess you should contact the host and see how to structure a proper request for it should it be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

How do you upload the video? If FTP, text transfer mode may have ruined the file. The hosting (especially, a free one) can impose a limit on the file size (uploaded or served) too. Or even on content types (e.g. narod.ru didn't allow to read files directly, serving a "download page" on an attempt instead).

Try to download the video file directly and compare it with the reference one.

Comment: No, the file is in an external server because I don't have enough space in my free web hosting. I want to just link it. The strange thing is that if I open the file directly in my Chrome browser or I load my html page from my local laptop, it works. So, probably I have some restriction from my hosting.

Comment: You cannot "have a restriction from your hosting" since the video file is requested by your browser directly. The most the free hosting can do is spoil the page itself. You may check its source in your browser. If your browser allows to, you may see the HTTP requests and responses too (or use a sniffer for that unless it's HTTPS), this should shed light on what is happening.

Comment: I think it's a restriction from the server hosting the video. Indeed, I tried to host my HTML page into my local Apache web server and even in this case, it doesn't work.

Comment: The only difference between a local page and a hosted page case is the `Referer:` header. If you are able to access the video's URL directly, this indeed must be a restriction by this header at the server hosting the video. I'd still like to see the HTTP requests and responses in local HTML and hosted HTML cases to state this with confidence.